# Web Application using Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I want to create a website which is used to digitize an image(Satellite image, Maps. etc) with the digitizing tools of point, line and polygon. Need suggestion to start up.

Comment: If you want to use java you will need to make an Applet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study Java EE, particularly Servlets and JSP. [This](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005405.do) was the reference that I used.

Basically, you need to understand the MVC(model-view-controller) pattern.

Lastly, learn how to incorporate your CSS/HTML/JavaScript/etc in your JSP.

Comment: Or you can also study Groovy and Grails and make your life a lot easier. :)